# How to pass down certain props based off of certain screen size

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hey guys I am currently curious about how to pass down different props based upon how big the width of the screen is.

Here's the function I am trying to modify:

```
export const Community: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({
  communityTeam,
  summary,
}) => (
  <div>
    <Container debug={false}>
      <Grid>
        <Cell full={true}>
          <h2 className="mll-community__title ray-text--monospace ray-text--body">
            Community Team
          </h2>
        </Cell>
        // If screen size is greater than 800px in width run this with Cell span passed down as 3.
        {communityTeam.map((member) => (
          <Cell span={3}>
            <div className="ray-card">
              <div className="ray-card__content">
                <div className="mll-community__avatar">
                  <Avatar image={member.imageUrl} />
                </div>
                <div className="mll-community__name">
                  <p className="ray-text">{member.name}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="mll-community__dashed-line" />
                <div className="mll-community__position">
                  <p className="ray-text">{member.position}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Cell>
        ))}
        // Otherwise pass down Cell span as 2 if it is less than 800 px.
        {communityTeam.map((member) => (
          <Cell span={3}>
            <div className="ray-card">
              <div className="ray-card__content">
                <div className="mll-community__avatar">
                  <Avatar image={member.imageUrl} />
                </div>
                <div className="mll-community__name">
                  <p className="ray-text">{member.name}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="mll-community__dashed-line" />
                <div className="mll-community__position">
                  <p className="ray-text">{member.position}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Cell>
        ))}
        <Cell full={true}>
          <p className="ray-text mll-community__summary">{summary}</p>
        </Cell>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  </div>
);
```

I'm not sure whether this is a problem involving media queries but I want to do something along the lines like so:

```
// If screen size is greater than 800px in width run this with Cell span passed down as 3.
        {communityTeam.map((member) => (
          <Cell span={3}>
            <div className="ray-card">
              <div className="ray-card__content">
                <div className="mll-community__avatar">
                  <Avatar image={member.imageUrl} />
                </div>
                <div className="mll-community__name">
                  <p className="ray-text">{member.name}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="mll-community__dashed-line" />
                <div className="mll-community__position">
                  <p className="ray-text">{member.position}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Cell>
        ))}
        // Otherwise pass down Cell span as 2 if the width of the screen is less than 800 px.
        {communityTeam.map((member) => (
          <Cell span={2}>
            <div className="ray-card">
              <div className="ray-card__content">
                <div className="mll-community__avatar">
                  <Avatar image={member.imageUrl} />
                </div>
                <div className="mll-community__name">
                  <p className="ray-text">{member.name}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="mll-community__dashed-line" />
                <div className="mll-community__position">
                  <p className="ray-text">{member.position}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Cell>
        ))}
```

Is there any way to pass down props depending on the size of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `resize` event listener to your component. So you can get the width of the screeen even though user resize it

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { width: 0, height: 0 };
  this.updateWindowDimensions = this.updateWindowDimensions.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.updateWindowDimensions();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
}

updateWindowDimensions() {
  this.setState({ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight });
}
```

Then in `render` you can check `width` to pass down specific `props`.

```
// If screen size is greater than 800px in width run this with Cell span passed down as 3.
        {width >= 800 ? communityTeam.map((member) => (
          <Cell span={3}>
            <div className="ray-card">
              <div className="ray-card__content">
                <div className="mll-community__avatar">
                  <Avatar image={member.imageUrl} />
                </div>
                <div className="mll-community__name">
                  <p className="ray-text">{member.name}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="mll-community__dashed-line" />
                <div className="mll-community__position">
                  <p className="ray-text">{member.position}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Cell>))
        : communityTeam.map((member) => (
          <Cell span={2}>
            <div className="ray-card">
              <div className="ray-card__content">
                <div className="mll-community__avatar">
                  <Avatar image={member.imageUrl} />
                </div>
                <div className="mll-community__name">
                  <p className="ray-text">{member.name}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="mll-community__dashed-line" />
                <div className="mll-community__position">
                  <p className="ray-text">{member.position}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Cell>
        ))}
```

Comment: This would involve putting my render code inside a class correct?